# Saber si existe un dato especifico dentro de una o varias tablas enteras

Tags: php, mysql

Existe alguna manera de no escribir cada una de los campos dentro del WHERE ya que son varias tablas en las que debo buscar si existe ese dato x

```
SELECT * FROM tabla1 as t1
INNER JOIN tabla2 AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
INNER JOIN tabla3 AS t3 ON t1.id = t3.id
INNER JOIN tabla4 AS t4 ON t1.id = t4.id 
INNER JOIN tabla5 AS t5 ON t1.id = t5.id 
INNER JOIN tabla6 AS t6 ON t1.id = t6.id 
INNER JOIN tabla7 AS t7 ON t1.id = t7.id 
WHERE CAP.id='35' AND (t2.cualquier_columna CONTAINS(x) OR t3.cualquier_columna CONTAINS(x) etc etc etc)
```

Porque cada tabla contiene alrededor de 12 campos y debo saber si por lo menos 1 de esos campos contiene ese dato x. Espero haberme explicado lo suficientemente bien.

Comment: Debes de saber si lo que quieres es buscar en todos los campos de una tabla, eso no se puede,  a parte si de alguna forma lo haces es muuuuyyy ineficiente, es mejor centrarse en un campo de una o varias tablas

Comment: Indicas que usas `php`, por lo tanto no debería ser problema montar una consulta todo lo larga o compleja que necesites, basta con meter los campos y tablas en arrays y montar la consulta con un bucle. Si fuera para ejecutar por consola sería diferente. Pero olvídate de JOINS, buscar en cada tabla por separado así en cuanto encuentres el dato ya no continúas buscando. Dependiendo del framework usado para base de datos la solución seria diferente, si no usas ningún framework te aconsejo que te montes una serie de funciones para acceder a base de datos que te agilicen las consultas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo más cercano sería una implementación como esta. Supongamos que buscas la palabra "manzana"

```
SELECT * FROM tabla1 as t1
INNER JOIN tabla2 AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
INNER JOIN tabla3 AS t3 ON t1.id = t3.id
INNER JOIN tabla4 AS t4 ON t1.id = t4.id 
INNER JOIN tabla5 AS t5 ON t1.id = t5.id 
INNER JOIN tabla6 AS t6 ON t1.id = t6.id 
INNER JOIN tabla7 AS t7 ON t1.id = t7.id 
WHERE CAP.id='35' AND CONCAT(t2.cualquier_columna, '', t3.cualquier_columna etc etc) LIKE "%manzana%"
```

Y así sucesivamente. Aún así, **no te lo recomiendo**, pues es probable que haciendo esto tengas problemas con los campos `NULL`.

Simplemente comprueba manualmente en todos los campos: creo que no hay forma de hacer una consulta SQL que busque en todos los campos sin declarar explícitamente el campo para buscar. La razón es que **existe una teoría de bases de datos relacionales y reglas estrictas para manipular datos relacionales** (álgebra relacional; de esto es de lo que proviene SQL), y **la teoría no permite cosas como "*simplemente buscar en todos los campos***". Por supuesto, el comportamiento real depende de la realización concreta del proveedor. Pero en el caso general, no es posible.

Si el problema es tener que escribir tu dato varias veces cada vez que hagas una búsqueda, podrías declararlo como una variable, de esta forma.

```
SET @dato = 'manzana'

SELECT * FROM tabla1 as t1
INNER JOIN tabla2 AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
INNER JOIN tabla3 AS t3 ON t1.id = t3.id
INNER JOIN tabla4 AS t4 ON t1.id = t4.id 
INNER JOIN tabla5 AS t5 ON t1.id = t5.id 
INNER JOIN tabla6 AS t6 ON t1.id = t6.id 
INNER JOIN tabla7 AS t7 ON t1.id = t7.id 
WHERE CAP.id='35' AND (t2.cualquier_columna LIKE '%@dato%' OR t3.cualquier_columna LIKE '%@dato%' etc etc etc)
```